# Importing modules globally

Tags: python, import

I would like to provide users with a python script which would import some modules for them and then drop to the python interpreter with the imported modules available at that level. I have some code which I thought might work, but it does not seem to:

```
module_list = ['module_a','module_b']

# Import our common modules
for module in module_list:
try:
    print "Importing: {0}".format(module)
    exec("import {0}".format(module))
except:
    print "FYI we failed importing {0}. It will not be available for you to use".format(module)
```

So when the script is done it will drop to the python module where the user can do:

```
>>> module_a.run()
```

Comment: Have you considered using the IPython shell? It's much more comfortable and it supports embedding for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Against the advise of many comments I have read on touching `__main__`, I did it.

So here is the code that ended up working for me:

```
module_list = ['module_a','module_b']

# Import our modules
for name in module_list:
     try:
         __import__(name)
        if name in sys.modules:
            setattr(__main__, name, sys.modules[name])
     except:
        print "FYI we failed importing {0}. It will not be available for you to use".format(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`code.InteractiveConsole()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html#code.InteractiveConsole) and pass a `locals` dictionary containing the local context in which the console will run. By storing the modules in there you can easily make them available to the interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this, if I were you.. but

```
import imp

module_list = ['module_a','module_b']

for name in module_list:
    try:
        module_info = imp.find_module(name)
        globals()[name] = imp.load_module(name, *module_info)
    except:
        "Import error: %s" %name
```

save above code file, for example `imptest.py` and load it with `-i` switch, as

```
python -i imptest.py
```

Comment: No need for `imp`. Just use the builtin [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function. `globals()[name] = __import__(name)`

Comment: The problem is that at the python prompt the imported module is not available this way.